# EmberJS: how to prevent Ember from interfering with jQuery.extend?

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember app, I need to manipulate (sorting, filtering, etc) tons of non-UI related objects. Since there is a lot of them and they are deeply nested, I don't declare them as Ember Objects, but "pure" Javascript ones (arrays and {}). I don't need all the Ember mixins.

My app was starting to become slow. Looking into the details, here is what I found:

At some point I do a simple:

```
var b = $.extend(true, [], a); // a is a pure javascript object
```

but when I inspect b, it looks like it has been changed into an Ember object. It has a bunch of properties like addArrayObserver, addBeforeObserver and so on.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks

PJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember automatically extends the default Javascript array to add functionality, so you get these additions even if you create a 'pure' Javascript array with `[]`.

You can disable these extensions by setting a configuration flag before Ember.js is loaded:

```
window.Ember = {};
Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES = false;
```

This is detailed in [one of the guide pages](http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed this. It is pretty "heavy" though, it means I would have to rewrite tons of code. Do you by chance know if there is a way to create a specific instance of an array WITHOUT the Ember extensions? I mean if you do `Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES = false;` then you can create an Ember array with Ember.A(...), but is there a trick to make it work in the opposite case (EXTEND_PROTOTYPES being set to true)?

Comment: It seems like it is an all or nothing and you can't pick and choose, at least as far as I can see.